# Display variable from php file into a html file

Tags: php, html, forms, logic

This questions looks stupid, but I'm not able to pass the variable $total from my php file to a html form withou using the include_once. I cannot use include_once at the beginning of the html file, because I'm using temp variable and it will give a error if I try to do it. I would like to include it directly into the form.

My php file `doRequest.php` has all the application logic and I have this variable `$total` that come from my logic and I want to print inside of the form. My method `addGradeValueToUsers` receives two parameters from different files. How I do to display `$total` inside of my method?

```
<form action="doRequest.php" id='requestForm' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Add Grades" onclick="addGradeValueToUsers(<?php echo $total; ?>"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: So $total is a PHP variable= It's outside the `<?php echo ... ?> ` tags, was that intended?

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo $course comes from a different php file. Btw the variables there is a comma too.

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo I'm getting this error: Undefined variable: total in C:\Users\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\htdocs\Project\views\index.php on line 95 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0574384280{main}( )...\index.php:0 )"/>

Comment: Is there a reason using `(<?php echo $course . ',' . $total; ?>)` doesn't work?

Comment: @Dave Even if I try only  $total, it doesn't not work. The variable to $total is inside of doRequest.php that add to action in the form.

Comment: Did you try to pass it via cookie?

Comment: @mitkosoft I just tried it, but does not recognize the variable.

Comment: Regarding the code shown above, $total is outside PHP tag, so it is parsed as JS variable, but not as PHP ones.

Comment: @mitkosoft if I do that: (<?php echo $total; ?>"/> )  it does not work. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: @Maple 'Undefined variable' means you haven't created it (stored something in it) before trying to echo it

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo that I know, what I do not know is how to store it in variable to be used outside of AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `total` variable's value through a cookie:

```
<?php
//doRequest.php
$total = someInternalLogic();
setcookie('total', $total);
?>

<!-- php that contains the form -->
<form action="doRequest.php" id='requestForm' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Add Grades" onclick="addGradeValueToUsers(<?php echo $_COOKIE['total']; ?>)"/>
</form>
```

Be aware that `setcookie()` must be called before any HTML output in your `doRequest.php` file (if any).

Comment: in case I load some data before and because of that, it does no work.

Comment: Nobody can help you if you don’t provide entire use case and enough code.